# Typescript (wrong?) type assumption on enum property

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain me, why typescript thinks it knows that `myClass.prop` in the last line is `EnumA.Y`? I would think it should always be `EnumA`? What's the correct way to handle this behavior?

```
enum EnumA {
    X,
    Y,
}

class MyClass {
    prop: EnumA = EnumA.X;

    change() {
        this.prop = EnumA.X;
    }
}

const myClass = new MyClass();
console.log(myClass.prop) // (property) MyClass.prop: EnumA
myClass.prop = EnumA.Y;
console.log(myClass.prop) // (property) MyClass.prop: EnumA.Y
myClass.change();
console.log(myClass.prop) // (property) MyClass.prop: EnumA.Y <-- NOT CORRECT
```

Link to Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEEoG8BQUNQBoBp2YE08BfVVAYwBsBDAZ1qgFkBPAYRvpXwwAcAnAPY8AXLHhIAvGMgIAdFgDcZTFHIALaiADmwABQBKLipUAXNQEtas-kKhS4M+UpWlSFASFomoENhwZSIMAA7kx+dLQGSuQetAKUwLKUAlq6vuwR1oI8hgD0uVC6NjzAfCbMhiwZ9FlCog6IqOn+tTx20oiyBNGx8YnJqc2ZxXkFRdml5ZXhNcX14l1NM1bqmjpR7p59SSlpy62jhcWTFWHVVnMdcgRAA

Edit: If i try the same with number or string instead of enums, it does work.

Edit2: Here is a screenshot of the problem. The code works fine, but the type assumed by TS is wrong.

[image: Problem in playground]

SOLUTION: After checking the linked question, this might be the best "fix":
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEEoG8BQUNQBoBp2YE08BfVVAYwBsBDAZ1qgFkBPAYRvpXwwAcAnAPY8AXLHhIAvGMgIAdFgDcZTFHIALaiADmwABQBKLipUAXNQEtas-kKhS4M+UpWlSFASFomoENhwZSIMAA7kx+dLQGSuQetAKUwLKUAlq6vuwR1oI8hgD0uVC6NjzAfCbMhiwZ9FlCog6IqOn+tTx20oiyBFB0HQjRsfGJyanNmcV5BUXZpeWV4TXF9eJNC1bqmjpR7p5DSSlpa62ThcWzFWHVVkt9QA

```
[...]
const myClass = new MyClass();
console.log(myClass.prop) // (property) MyClass.prop: EnumA
myClass.prop = EnumA.Y as EnumA;
console.log(myClass.prop) // (property) MyClass.prop: EnumA
myClass.change();
console.log(myClass.prop) // (property) MyClass.prop: EnumA
```

Comment: In the playground it works well. You are setting `myClass.prop` to `enum.X` and this is 0.

Comment: Yes, it works, but Typescript assumes, that myClass.prop is EnumA.Y. You can see that, if you hover over the prop and look at the type.
The problem comes im more complex scenarios. This is the minimal example to show the problem.